# php - mysqli count rows with specific value

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I'm able to count all the record's in a table with the value *"Waiting"*. This is done by using:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS SUM FROM jobs WHERE status='Waiting'";
```

When I want to echo the row count I just do:

```
echo $rows['SUM'];
```

How can I do it so it also count's all the record's in a table with the value *"Ready"*?

Comment: Do you want to count everyone who is either `waiting or ready` or do you need to count everyone who is `waiting` and then everyone who is `ready`?

Answer (score 3):

This query will return all `status` count divided by status:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS tot FROM jobs GROUP BY status
```

The resulting set is something like this:

```
status       tot
-----------  ------
Waiting      123
Ready        80
...          56
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want `status='Waiting'` or `status='Ready'`? You can separate parameters with `OR` or `AND`; for example:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS SUM FROM jobs WHERE status='Waiting' OR status='Ready'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(status) AS 'count' FROM jobs GROUP BY status HAVING status='Ready'
```

This will count the records with the status = Ready. You use GROUP BY to get an aggregate on the status field. And because you have used GROUP BY, you use HAVING (which is the equivalent of WHERE in GROUP situations) to filter the data.

Answer (score -1):

By using `IN` operator in your query.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS SUM FROM jobs WHERE status IN ('Waiting','Ready')";
```

Get group based(**status**) counts by using `GROUP BY` operator

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS SUM FROM jobs GROUP BY status";
```

Print the status based result.

```
//Create the `mysqli_connection` and assign to `$conn` variable.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 

if($result->num_rows>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {           
        echo "<br>status=" . $row['status'];
        echo "<br>SUM=" . $row['SUM'];
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I echo the count of the rows individually. For example the total jobs Waiting, and the total jobs Ready.

Comment: Check in my edited answer. It will help you to print the result.